# Objective-C char from NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, nsnotification

In my NSNotificationCenter I have something like:

```
    NSMutableDictionary *info = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:1];
    [info setObject:[NSNumber numberWithChar:cmd[3]] forKey:@"baud"];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"baud" object:nil userInfo:info];
```

Now I would like to have this char back. 
I need something like:

```
NSDictionary *userInfo = [note userInfo];
char rate = [userInfo objectForKey:@"baud"];
```

Comment: Note that `char` is almost certainly the wrong type to use in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are packing the char into an `NSNumber`, so you need to extract it again:

```
char rate = [(NSNumber *)[userInfo objectForKey:@"baud"] charValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char rate = [[userInfo objectForKey:@"baud"] charValue];
```